# Not able to create new device in Android emulator VS 2019

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, android-emulator, visual-studio-2019, android-device-manager

I am new to the Xamarin development following the Microsoft getting started docs.

In the **Android Device Manager** I am seeing blank when I click **New Device**.

[image: Android Device manager is empty]

Can any one please tell me how to fix this issue.

**Edit : Adding more images of the settings and SDK for reference**.

[image: VS2019 Xamarin Options]

[image: Android SDK platform section]

[image: Android SDK tools section]

**Note : Added Hyper-V and installed Google API's from the SDK checked the path, everything looks correct.**

Answer (score 0):

You should change Base Device, Processor and OS on the left menu first.

Comment: There are few options in the Base device when I select it the Android Device manager is getting hanged and ask to close.The other two drop downs are empty. Not sure why this strange behaviour is :(

Answer (score 0):

Please recheck if you have installed the android sdk correctly. Visual Studio includes an Android SDK Manager that you use to download Android SDK tools, platforms, and other components that you need for developing Xamarin.Android apps.

For this, you can check the official document [Setting up the Android SDK for Xamarin.Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-sdk?tabs=windows) .  This guide explains how to use the Xamarin Android SDK Manager in Visual Studio and Visual Studio for Mac.

Comment: yes I followed the same documentation, added few more screenshots for reference

Comment: You can try to repair your visual studio. For more details, check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

Comment: Yes, I tried this also. Unfortunately no luck.

Comment: You can report this problem in VS support topic here: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/